# Why is WSL2 blocking me from editing/saving files on Windows 10 using VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've used this setup for months and basically the context is that I messed with my WLS2 which used to work fine. I ended up unninstalling it using "apps and features" on settings, and then installing it again running "`wsl --install`" on PowerShell there is no more options for unninstalling it using the same "apps and featuress" and now every time I try to save a file I get an error:

> Failed to save 'FILE': Unable to write file 'vscode remote://wsl+ubuntu/home/ (No permission (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/')

I just want to understand what is happening and why although it worked well before, now it doesn't, and also how do i solve this problem...

One of my trials was running "`chmod 777`" or something like that (don't understand that really, just copying commands from the internet) but it ran over all my files even outside the WSL enviroment and after a while I just killed the process. It didn't work though, I got the same errors.

Comment: I guess you are using WSL2 for docker or rancher, so are you getting any error in them?

Comment: what's the full path in the error message? Why did you crop it off?

Comment: It's not a permissions issue. See **Cannot access WSL files from Windows** in [Troubleshooting WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting)

Comment: The error was cropped because the rest of it is just personal specific information